# Creating .pem file from pushnotification with PHP under LINUX w

Tags: php, iphone, apple-push-notifications

i'm trying to implement push notification in my application, for this i tried to use easyApns, i follow the steps, and implement the classes on my linux based. but unfortunately i stil betting some errors related to certificates.

my error is:

> Warning: stream_socket_client() [function.stream-socket-client]: SSL
>   operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
>   error:14094416:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert certificate
>   unknown in /var/www/html/apns/classes/class_APNS.php on line 401
>
> Warning: stream_socket_client() [function.stream-socket-client]:
>   Failed to enable crypto in /var/www/html/apns/classes/class_APNS.php
>   on line 401
>
> Warning: stream_socket_client() [function.stream-socket-client]:
>   unable to connect to ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195
>   (Unknown error) in /var/www/html/apns/classes/class_APNS.php on line
>   401
>
> Notice: Failed to connect to APNS: 0 . 1) APNS::__construct -> File:
>   apns.php (line 50) 2) APNS::_fetchMessages -> File: class_APNS.php
>   (line 217) 3) APNS::_pushMessage -> File: class_APNS.php (line 376) 4)
>   APNS::_triggerError -> File: class_APNS.php (line 405) in
>   /var/www/html/apns/classes/class_APNS.php on line 509

i gusse it's an error related to the certificate (the .pem file)

my .pem file wa generated using the following command

> openssl pkcs12 -in apns-dev-cert.p12 -out apns-dev-cert.pem -nodes -clcerts

and it was placed on the server (linux based) and given chmod 644 privileges

should i do any thing else.....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you able to connect to apns using your certificate? try following command to check that:

> $ openssl s_client -connect gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 -cert YourSSLCertAndPrivateKey.pem -debug -showcerts -CAfile server-ca-cert.pem

If the command terminates, you are not able to connect. If it continues running and lets you type into the socket, you have connected successfully.

Answer (score 1):

I have found out that for the command to work it is necessary to :

1. create a certificate signing request (.csr) and upload it to the apple dev portal
2. download the provided .p12 license
3. transform it to a pem file using the certificate + your machine private key
4. download and install the certificate from Entrust

reference:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2265/_index.html

Comment: I still don't know how to do this step on linux:
"Double-clicking the file launches Keychain Access. Make sure you install the certificate in your login keychain on the computer you are using for provider development. In Keychain Access, ensure that your certificate user ID matches your application’s bundle ID. The APNs SSL certificate should be installed on your notification server."
maybe add the certificate somewhere to openssl conf or apache conf?

Comment: all problems solved, finally a SE security issue that prevented the php script to work from browser. 
I just had to check the logs, and try the script from command line

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue.
Downloaded the .p12 file then
$ openssl pkcs12 -in apns-dev-cert.p12 -out apns-dev-cert.pem -nodes -clcerts
then using Nilesh command:
$ openssl s_client -connect gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 -cert YourSSLCertAndPrivateKey.pem -debug -showcerts -CAfile server-ca-cert.pem
then i get this error

unable to load client certificate private key file
140405386606400:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:pem_lib.c:696:Expecting: ANY PRIVATE KEY

thanks

Comment: did you replace YourSSLCertAndPrivateKey.pem from my command with your filename? e.g. apns-dev-cert.pem

Comment: thanks. Yes, but what is the server-ca-cert.pem in your command?

Comment: I just found out here that server-ca-cert.pem is the certificate provided by Entrust, and used along the other certificate(s) to communicate with the apns
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2265/_index.html

Comment: Yes you are correct. Root CA certificate is needed to establish the chain of trust.

Answer (score 0):

Double check that before to generate the .pem,
you export correctly the "2" items from Keychain:

Apple Development IOS Push Services + user name key.

Then export the2 items