# setting up a linux provider for Apple Push Notification Service (APNS)

Tags: iphone, linux, apple-push-notifications

Salaam,

I am referring to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7173678/creating-pem-file-from-pushnotification-with-php-under-linux-w) to setup a linux provider.

I think the difference between the [main tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12) and the Linux version has to do with how the certificates are installed/stored/used..etc

These are the steps I have done with their status:

- **ok** : create app-id
- **ok** : upload provider .csr
- **ok** : download apns certificate .p12
- **ok** : transform it to .pem and concatenate with provider privatekey.pem
- **ok** : test connection with cmd 1; successfull in showing "connected000003" and some text
- **ok** : test connection with cmd 2 (using Entrust CA)
- **nok**: test push message using tutorial's simple php: **permission denied**

> cmd1: openssl s_client -connect gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195
>   -cert apns-dev-
>       cert.pem -key privateKey.pem
>
> cmd2: openssl s_client -connect gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195
>   -cert ck.pem -debug -showcerts -CAfile server-ca-cert.pem

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using easyapns. Maybe in the sql database you aren't in sandbox mode? If you have permission denied try to chmod the php file to 777

Comment: I did switch the flag to sandbox mode

Answer (score 0):

my target is easyapns, but I was testing with simpepush.php provided with the first tutorial. suprinsingly, the script worked from the command line but not from the browser !

now i'm trying easyapns from browser and it's working.

More suprisingly, I just had to use the ck.pem from the mac machine, uploaded to the linux box

I am unable to explain why...

Comment: the difference between command line and browser based php was a SE security issue: setbool httpd_can_network_relay 1
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=804350